# /dev/kvm error from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting a /dev/kvm error in Android Studio.
I have enabled the VT-X from BIOS Setting (in Windows 7)

[image]

Comment: is KVM installed in your system ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more than just enabling it in the BIOS. Have a look at this guide for enabling it on linux distributions:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator

Comment: Hello seanAshmore  I  already mention here that  i am currently using window 7 .

Comment: Woops sorry, here's one for windows:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: Thank you seanAshmore but
I already install  Intel HAXM  package to achieve virtualization